# How to clear search bar - The method 'clear' was called on null

Tags: android, flutter, dart, searchbar

Im using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/material_floating_search_bar/example

and i dont want to use the method .searchToClear() in the actions.

i want to add my custom icon, so im trying to clear the searchbar when onPressed is called. But i get this:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'clear' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: clear()
```

this is my code

```
_searchBar() {
    return FloatingSearchBar(
      backdropColor: Colors.transparent,
      hint: 'Search...',
      scrollPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 56),
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
      transitionCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      openAxisAlignment: 0.0,
      debounceDelay: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      onQueryChanged: (query) {
        // Call your model, bloc, controller here.
      },
      // Specify a custom transition to be used for
      // animating between opened and closed stated.
      transition: CircularFloatingSearchBarTransition(),
      actions: [
        // FloatingSearchBarAction.searchToClear(
        //   showIfClosed: false,
        // ),
        FloatingSearchBarAction.icon(
            showIfClosed: false,
            showIfOpened: true,
            icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
            onTap: () {
              final bar = FloatingSearchAppBar.of(context);
              bar.clear();
              print(bar);
            }),
      ],
      builder: (context, transition) {
        return ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 4.0,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: Colors.accents.map((color) {
                return Container(height: 112, color: color);
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Update:

You only need to accept `BuildContext` as arguments if you use any context related inside the function.

From the documentation itself, you need to declare a controller to be able to control `close` and `clear` of the search bar. This means it have to be inside a `statefulWidget` since it have something that change.

1. First, we have to declare `FloatingSearchBarController _floatingSearchBarController = FloatingSearchBarController();`
2. Inside the button we can use either `_floatingSearchBarController.clear()` or `_floatingSearchBarController.close()`

Example using your code to demonstrate as below:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:material_floating_search_bar/material_floating_search_bar.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  FloatingSearchBarController _floatingSearchBarController = FloatingSearchBarController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Hello Floating'),),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text('World'),
          ), 
          _searchBar(),
        ]
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _searchBar() {
    return FloatingSearchBar(
      controller: _floatingSearchBarController,
      backdropColor: Colors.transparent,
      hint: 'Search...',
      clearQueryOnClose: true, // INSERT THIS
      scrollPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 56),
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
      transitionCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      openAxisAlignment: 0.0,
      debounceDelay: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      onQueryChanged: (query) {
        // Call your model, bloc, controller here.
      },
      // Specify a custom transition to be used for
      // animating between opened and closed stated.
      transition: CircularFloatingSearchBarTransition(),
      actions: [
        FloatingSearchBarAction.icon(
              showIfClosed: false,
              showIfOpened: true,
              icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
              onTap: () {
                // FloatingSearchBar.of(context)
                _floatingSearchBarController.clear();
                _floatingSearchBarController.close();
                // FloatingSearchBar.of(context).close();
                // final bar = FloatingSearchAppBar.of(context);
                // bar.clear();
                // print(bar);
        }),
        
      ],
      builder: (context, transition) {
        return ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 4.0,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: Colors.accents.map((color) {
                return Container(height: 112, color: color);
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: its returns me: 
The method 'close' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: close()

Comment: I fix the explanation and add example code, that should help